# Is 'The student asked to be excused the examination' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I am a high school student. I just want to know that, is this statement grammatically correct?

"The student asked to be excused the examination"

Comment: Not if it's an English test.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **excused** here takes the preposition **from**, so you would need to say:

> The student asked to be excused **from** the examination.